# Is THROWS required if using try / catch?

Tags: java, exception

If there is a try / catch block  with my code is it required that there is a throws statement  after the method header?

If it is NOT required , then when would/why would I need to use throws? - is it just to stop the compiler failing ?(i.e. im telling it im expecting an error and thats ok)

Comment: It's an either/or type of situation which depends on what you want at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the `throws` keyword is for when it is not correct to use a `try` block to handle the exception within the method itself.

When your code throws a checked exception, you must either use a `try` block to catch it, or use the `throws` keyword on your method to advertise the fact that it throws an exception to any method that may call it, so that it in turn must either use a `try` block to catch it or use the `throws` keyword to pass the buck. You *cannot* do both (unless you're dealing with more than one exception.)

It's a design decision you have to make. Either the method you're writing knows how to handle the exception and does so, or it doesn't and it throws the exception to its callers.

Comment: so if i had a method with throws and called that method from somewhere else I would HAVE to use either throws in the calling method header or have a try/catch block in the calling method to avoid an error? I.e. if I didnt it isnt going to work (its not enough to have the called method with throws)

Comment: Yes. That is, for checked exceptions. Exceptions which extend RuntimeException are unchecked; every method implicitly throws RuntimeException. When you write a checked exception, you're informing your caller, "Hey, this might fail." A typical example is reading from a file. The method will throw an IOException if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

When your method has some code segment that throws an exception, your method has two options:

> catch the exception in method body and handle it,

or

> throws the exception to the place from where the method was called.

In the first instance, your method will have a try/catch block to handle the exception. In the second instance, your method will be declared with throws and the method that will call this method, will have to use the try/catch block.